# Can I transfer my PhD to another university (the university's offer I had rejected)?

Tags: phd, transfer-student

I am doing PhD (1st year) at University X and my advisor hasn't been finalized yet since the professor working in the field in which I was interested didn't have much funding. Now I am left with the option of either working with another professor whose area of specialization is different or working in collaboration with other 2 professors. Given the circumstances and their field of work, I am not sure whether to continue with PhD at X.
However, before joining this university I had an offer from a professor at University Y(in whose work I was interested) but I rejected his offer to go to my current university.
Should reaching out to him for readmission can be an option?

Comment: It never hurts to ask. If you can ask the question on academia.se, you can just as easily send an email to the professor at Y and ask about this. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can reach out, but your chances might not be great for lots of reasons. He may not have an opening at the moment. And he might question your dedication. Nothing is certain. But you can ask. Don't burn local bridges in the meantime.